# Rounding off the numbers less than 1 in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I tried the following:

ROUND (0.55, 0)

But, it returns the value 0 whereas I want 1. Isn't there any other ways to obtain value 1 in MYSQL?

Comment: Not in my computer... Can you please share the full code and specs?

Comment: I have 1 for your code. You can try ROUND (0.55)

Comment: @SamIvichuk - Sorry but [I cant' see the difference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round). Could you elaborate about that?

Comment: Counter-example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/33259

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Yes, there is no difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issues is described in mysql's documentation on [round()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round) function, specifically:

> For approximate-value numbers, the result depends on the C library. On many systems, this means that ROUND() uses the "round to nearest even" rule: A value with any fractional part is rounded to the nearest even integer.

0.55 cannot be exactly represented in binary, therefore an approximate number is used, which is subject to the above mentioned behaviour. If the C library on the give operating system uses "round to nearest even" rule, then 0.55 will be rounded to 0.

To imitate the "round halfway up" method, add 0.5 to the number being rounded and take the integer part: `floor(x+0.5)`.